# how can i restart app when user close the app in Android

Tags: java, android

I have chronometer in my fragment. If user start the chronometer start button's visibility is invisible and stop button's visibility is visible. I want to if user start the chronometer and use the another app, chronometer reset and start button's visibility is visible. Shortly i want to reset fragment when user close my app. How can i do that?

```
baslat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {


               chronometer.setFormat("%s");
               chronometer.start();
               chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());


               baslat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
               bitir.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

           }
       });


       bitir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               chronometer.stop();


           }
       });
```

Comment: Use the fragment lifecycle method.

Comment: Hi @Murat Cem Erenoğlu, if my answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Thank you. I am new in here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of `onPause()` or `onStop()` life cycle methods depending on what you are trying to achieve.

take a look at [fragment life cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) to understand more.

this should be enough to help with your issue. if you need more clarifications let me know.